# Strike at Lyon airport (Aviapartner) on July 16, 2022?

Tags: compensation, lys

I had a flight to Lyon cancelled and the airline refused compensation because the reason for the cancellation would be a strike at a handling company Aviapartner at Lyon airport.

Now I do find other airlines cancelling flights on July 16, but I do not find any information from trade unions, local newspapers or the airport itself mentioning the strike. Whereas I do easily find information about earlier strikes of the company.

The cancellation took place during a very messy summer with lack of staff across airlines with many flights cancelled for operational reasons. Also, many other flights with the same handling agent could take place as scheduled on July 16.

Can anyone provide me with some more information about a potential strike of Aviapartner LYS ?
Are there any other ways to check this information other than file a lawsuit against the airline and force them to come with proof?

Answer (score 2):

[This website](https://www.visa-algerie.com/air-algerie-risques-de-perturbations-au-depart-de-lyon/) explicitly mentions strikes expected on the 15th and 16th. LyonMag quoted trade unionists saying the strikes at AviaPartner [were going to "intensify"](https://www.lyonmag.com/article/124070/aeroport-lyon-saint-exupery-la-greve-va-s-amplifier-chez-aviapartner). There is ample but patchy coverage of strikes by airport staff that were happening around the same time in the local press but very little about AviaPartner specifically.

At the same time, I wouldn't expect the local press to faithfuly report every day of industrial action in an ongoing conflict (the main local newspapers seemed to have barely covered AviaPartner, with only [one article](https://www.leprogres.fr/transport/2022/06/03/aeroport-lyon-saint-exupery-preavis-de-greve-chez-aviapartner-pour-samedi) mentioning it in *Le Progrès* at the beginning of June). To me, reports of strikes before and after the 16th actually make the airline's account more credible. According to the reports I came across, only a part of the workforce was striking on any given day and not all flights were impacted so the fact that some flights did leave on the 16th does not seem very significant. The other cancellation you mention also lend the airline's account additional credibility.

Suing over this seems likely to be a waste of time and money.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

The first link you post to the press release of the union is from last year. I would indeed have expected something similar for strikes on my travel date.

The link to the Air Algerie flights indeed mentions strikes and flight cancellations, but the Air Algerie flights mentioned on the website have not been cancelled. So I am not sure the information on that website is correct.

We were 6 passengers, so compensation would be 1.500 EUR, that's quite some money.

Comment: @John I wil correct the answer, thanks. I don't think this website provides very strong evidence either but I also believe that's not the way you should look at it. If you actively look for reasons to believe there may not have been a strike, it only makes it too easy to engage in wishful thinking when in fact all we found is additional evidence that the airline's account is credible (including this website and the source you mentioned yourself).

Comment: I would rather recommend asking yourself if you have any positive reason to believe the airline may be acting in bad faith? Did you get another explanation on the day itself? Earlier bad experience of compensation denied under false pretense?

Comment: Your last link is about LYS airport staff. The strike 2 weeks earlier that is mentioned in the article was on July 13, so that was clearly not the reason for cancellation of my flight. Aviapartner indeed had several strikes earlier in July and June (all well documented in local newspapers and union's website), but apart from the Air Algerie information that tells flights would be cancelled because of a strike, that finally were not cancelled at all, I don't find much information for July 16.

Comment: And yes, I have reasons to believe the airline is acting in bad faith. I had several requests denied for extraordinary reasons that turned out not to be extraordinary at all. They basically denied everything at first, only to give in after I threaten them with legal action. And they have cancelled many flights in July since they have staff issues. I suspect them to abuse the turbulence at their handling partner to cancel flights they wanted to cancel anyway. Since that's difficult to prove, I was hoping to find someone with more insight into LYS operations.

Comment: @John None of these sources provides a complete account of all the strikes (the July 13th strike did not prompt any publication), we are talking about a few dozens people at most, I tried using their archive but it seems the local press (*Progrès* and *Dauphiné*) barely covered it at all so it does not seem reasonable to expect each and every day of strike documented online. So reading the evidence in such a biased way seems incredibly self-serving and just risks clouding your judgment.

Comment: The July 13 strike by LYS staff was well covered by e.g. Le Progres (https://www.leprogres.fr/social/2022/07/13/la-greve-a-l-aeroport-lyon-saint-exupery-pourrait-reprendre-cet-ete) or (https://www.leprogres.fr/social/2022/07/11/greve-a-l-aeroport-lyon-saint-exupery-ce-mercredi-des-perturbations-a-prevoir).

June 4: https://www.leprogres.fr/transport/2022/06/03/aeroport-lyon-saint-exupery-preavis-de-greve-chez-aviapartner-pour-samedi

Comment: I'm not trying to read evidence in a biased way, but trying to check the info the airline gave me, as I know for a fact (1) they're often lying about resaons of cancellation, (2) many flights with the same handling agent were not cancelled and (3) the airline was in trouble this summer and cancelled 100s of flights. And it turns out I find detailed info, either in a local newspaper or on the website of the unions, about *every* strike this summer, except a strike on Jul 16. That's why I am asking here if someone can provide more information. No need to keep on discussing news paper articles.

Comment: @John I looked for AviaPartner, which is why these articles didn't show up in my search as they don't mention them but Vinci. Are those the same strikes? Did you find any mention of the strikes at AviaPartner specifically (e.g. June 18 or June 24-25 if we believe LyonMag) in *Le Progrès*?

Comment: You don't want to discuss newspaper articles but it seems to be what led us down this rabbit hole. I do think you are reading the evidence in a biased way. I am just seeing plenty of evidence of ongoing strikes around this time, including a specific mention of a potential strike on the 16th. You yourself have been impacted and can attest that other flights were cancelled on that date and you have been told there was a strike.

Comment: The fact that Air Algérie wasn't impacted in the end of that we haven't found any newspaper article about the 16 specifically sound, to me, like a very weak basis to hold on to the belief that there may not have been a strike and that you should spend any time and money suing the airline.

Comment: An additional reason to doubt all this for me is that as I noted earlier no local media provides a complete account of strikes this summer. Some are mentioned in *Le Progrès*, some in *Lyon Mag*, some by the trade unions. You say you find a mention of every strike this summer but I see something completely different, namely that none of these sources can be relied on to cover them well and all of them did omit at least some strikes.

Comment: @John I corrected several inaccuracies in my answer, thanks for pointing those out.